# react js component polymorphism

Tags: reactjs

I have several identical forms with validation function.
I want to create another form with same behavior except validation function.

I try to use mixins for this, but mixins doesn't support method override.

What approach is the best for this problem?

This is an example of problem: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9150/

```
var FormMixin = {
    validate: function () {
        if (this.state.message !== '') {
            this.setState({status: 'ok'});
        } else {
            this.setState({status: 'error'});
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            message: 'Hello123!',
            status: ''
        };
    },
    handleChange: function (newValue) {
        this.setState({
            message: newValue
        });
    },
    valueLink: function() {
        return {
          value: this.state.message,
          requestChange: this.handleChange
        }     
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
         <div>
           <input type = "text" valueLink = {this.valueLink()} />
           <button onClick={this.validate} >Validate</button>
           <div>{this.state.status}</div>
         </div>
        );
    }
}

var Form = React.createClass({
    mixins: [FormMixin]
});

var FormEmpty = React.createClass({
    /*validate: function() { // How to override validation
      this.setState({status: 'ok'});
    },*/
    mixins: [FormMixin]
});

var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <Form />
            <Form />
            <Form />
            <FormEmpty />
        </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Mixins may not be the best approach and they don't fit well in the true JavaScript `class` model that is available in React 0.13+.

One simple alternative approach is to use an event/callback from the `Form` to a parent component which can provide custom validation ([jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/3mwzm6qn/1/)). For example:

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        validationOverride: React.PropTypes.func
    },

    validate: function () {
        if (this.props.validationOverride) {
            this.setState({status: this.props.validationOverride() });
            return;
        } 
        if (this.state.message !== '') {
            this.setState({status: 'ok'});
        } else {
        this.setState({status: 'error'});
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            message: 'Hello123!',
            status: ''
        };
    },
    handleChange: function (newValue) {
        this.setState({
            message: newValue
        });
    },
    valueLink: function() {
        return {
          value: this.state.message,
          requestChange: this.handleChange
        }     
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
         <div>
           <input type = "text" valueLink = {this.valueLink()} />
           <button onClick={this.validate} >Validate</button>
           <div>{this.state.status}</div>
         </div>
        );
    }
});

var FormEmpty = React.createClass({
    validate: function() {
        // you could pass in values to this function
        return "NOT OK!";
    },
    render: function() {
        return <Form validationOverride={ this.validate } />;    
    }
});
```

While I've left out some specifics (as it wasn't clear how your validation was going to work), you can see how I've created a second class called `FormEmpty` that contains a single child, `Form`. It passes a function as a callback called `validationOverride`. The `Form` calls that (if set) when validation needs to run. If it's not set, the standard validation logic applies.

Of course, you could choose to structure this so that there's a base class that never has validation and that it's always required to pass a validation function. In this way, you'd always need to do composition of a parent and a base form to perform validation (which would be a very common React pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at

https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form

https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-validation

It's quite handy if you are using simple form and validation.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a mixin factory that takes a validation function as parameter.

```
function FormMixin(validate) {
    return {
        validate: validate,
        /* ... */
    };
}

var Form = React.createClass({
    mixins: [FormMixin(validateMessage)]
});
```

Note that mixins can't override `render`. You might be better off creating a simple `Form` component that takes in a `validate` prop and reuse it in your other form components.